# TextView onTouchEvent within customview

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a custom view, and within the custom view I create 4 text views. I want each of these text views to respond to on touch events. However, the textviews themselves do not respond to an on touch event. I can however, make an ontouch listener for the entire custom view. However, I do not want the whole view to have an ontouch event because I want the textviews that I have created to be dragged and dropped. I tried going the route of registering the x and y coordinates of the ontouch event and assuming that if the ontouch event is within the bounds of a textview, to change the coordinates of the textview, but that was overly complicated because if one textview got dragged to the coordinates of another one, then the ontouch event would "pick up" the other textview, so then I'd be moving two text views, which is not what I want. So, to sum it up, I want to know if it's possible to set in ontouch listener for a textview inside a customview, and if possible, why it is not working:

```
                mScale.mPositive.get(0).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                        {
                                mScale.mCurrentXPos[0] = event.getX();
                                mScale.mCurrentYPos[0] = event.getY();
                                mScale.mDrag = true;

                            return true;
                        }

                    });
```

This same code works for the custom view, but not for the specific textviews inside that customview.

Here is the custom view code:

public class Scale extends View 
{

```
public Scale(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = this.getContext();
            h = new Handler();
            mCalendarDbHelper=new CalendarDbAdapter(mContext);
            mCalendarDbHelper.open();
    Cursor thoughts = mCalendarDbHelper.fetchThoughts();

    //create a string array of negative thoughts from the db
        while (thoughts.moveToNext())
        {
            if (thoughts.getString(thoughts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_THOUGHT)).length() > 0 && thoughts.getString(thoughts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_THOUGHT)).charAt(0) == '-')
            {
                negative_thoughts.add(thoughts.getString(thoughts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_THOUGHT)));
            }

        }
     thoughts.close();
     array_size = negative_thoughts.size();
     mBag =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bag);
     mGreenBag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_bag);

    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i ++)
    {
        try
        {
        mScale[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("scale_"+i+".gif"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

        }
    }
}


private Runnable r= new Runnable() 
{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        invalidate();

    }

};


protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas)
{
    if (first == true)
    {
        width = this.getWidth();
        height = this.getHeight();
        mScale[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mScale[i], (int) (width * 1.5), height, true);
        mBag = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBag, width/2, height/2, true);
        negative = new TextView(mContext);
        word = negative_thoughts.get((int) (Math.random() * array_size));
        negative.setText(word);
        negative.layout(0, 0, width/3, height/4);
        negative.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        negative.setTextSize(15);
        negative.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        negative.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        negative.setShadowLayer(5, 2, 2, Color.WHITE);
        negative.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        negative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.graycloud);
        positive_paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4444"));
        positive_paint.setShadowLayer(5, 2, 2, Color.YELLOW);
        positive_paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        positive_paint.setTextSize(25);
        mCurrentXPos[0] = (width/2);
        mCurrentYPos[0] = height/4;
        mCurrentXPos[1] = (width/2) + (width/8);
        mCurrentYPos[1] = height/6;
        mCurrentXPos[2] = width/2;
        mCurrentYPos[2] = height/12;
        mCurrentXPos[3] = (width/2) + (width/8);
        mCurrentYPos[3] = height/18;
        mMoveXPos[0] = ((width/2) - width)/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveYPos[0] = ((height/4) - (height + (height/4)))/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveXPos[1] = (((width/2) + (width/8)) - width)/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveYPos[1] = ((height/6) - (height + (height/4)))/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveXPos[2] = ((width/2) - width)/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveYPos[2] = ((height/12) - (height + (height/4)))/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveXPos[3] = (((width/2) + (width/8)) - width)/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveYPos[3] = ((height/18) - (height + (height/4)))/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByXPos[0] = -(width/2)/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByYPos[0] = -(height/4)/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByXPos[1] =  ((width - (width/3)) - (width/2 + (width/8)))/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByYPos[1] = -(height/6)/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByXPos[2] = - (width/2)/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByYPos[2] =  ((height) - (height/12))/FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByXPos[3] =  ((width - (width/3)) - (width/2 + (width/8)))/ FRAME_RATE;
        mMoveByYPos[3] =  ((height) - (height/18))/FRAME_RATE;
        currentX = width;
        currentY = height + height/4;
        first = false;
    }


    if (game_over == false)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mScale[i], 0 - (width/4), 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(negative.getDrawingCache(),(int) (width/12), (int) (height - (height)/2.5) - (j), null);
    }

    else
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBag, width/4, height/4, null);
    }

    if (mMoveScale == true)
    {
        i++;
        j+=3;
        ScaleIt(canvas, i);
        if (i == 21 || i == 37 || i == 53 || i == 71)
        {
            mMoveScale = false;
        }

    }

    if (tracker > 0)
    {
        if (tracker == 1)
        {
            if (currentX > width/2 && currentY > height/4 && sStop == false)
            {
                currentX += mMoveXPos[0]; 
                currentY += mMoveYPos[0];
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(tracker -1 ).getDrawingCache(), currentX, currentY, null);

            }

            else 
            {
                if (sStop == false)
                {


                    mMoveScale = true;
                    sStop = true;
                    currentX = width;
                    currentY = height + height/4;
                    draw_em++;
                }

            }
        }


        if (tracker == 2)
        {

            if (currentX > width/2 + (width/8) && currentY > (height/6) && sStop == false)
            {
                currentX += mMoveXPos[1]; 
                currentY += mMoveYPos[1];
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(tracker -1 ).getDrawingCache(), currentX, currentY, null);

            }

            else
            {
                if (sStop == false)
                {
                    mMoveScale = true;
                    sStop = true;
                    currentX = width;
                    currentY = height + height/4;
                    draw_em++;
                }
            }
        }


        if (tracker == 3)
        {

            if (currentX > width/2 && currentY > height/12 && sStop == false)
            {
                currentX += mMoveXPos[2]; 
                currentY += mMoveYPos[2];
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(tracker -1 ).getDrawingCache(), currentX, currentY, null);

            }

            else 
            {
                if (sStop == false)
                {
                    mMoveScale = true;
                    sStop = true;
                    currentX = width;
                    currentY = height + height/4;
                    draw_em++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (tracker == 4)
        {

            if (currentX > width/2 + (width/8) && currentY > (height/18) && sStop == false)
            {
                currentX += mMoveXPos[3]; 
                currentY += mMoveYPos[3];
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(tracker -1 ).getDrawingCache(), currentX, currentY, null);
            }

            else 
            {
                    if (sStop == false)
                    {
                    mMoveScale = true;
                    sStop = true;
                    game_over = true;
                    currentX = width;
                    currentY = height + height/4;
                    draw_em++;

                    }
            }
        }


        if (draw_em > 0 && game_over == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < draw_em; i ++)
            {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), width/2, height/4 + j, null);
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), width/2 + (width/8), height/6 + j, null);

            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), width/2, height/12 + j, null);


            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), width/2 + (width/8), height/18 + j, null);
            }

        }

        }

        else if (game_over == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < draw_em; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0 && mCurrentXPos[0] > 0 && mCurrentYPos[0] >  0 && mDrag == false)
                {

                    mCurrentXPos[0] += mMoveByXPos[0];
                    mCurrentYPos[0] += mMoveByYPos[0];
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), mCurrentXPos[0], mCurrentYPos[0], null);
                }

                else if (i == 0 && mCurrentXPos[0] <= 0 || mCurrentYPos[0] <=  0 && mDrag == false)
                { 
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(0).getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, null);
                }

                else if (i == 0 && mDrag == true)
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(0).getDrawingCache(), mCurrentXPos[0], mCurrentYPos[0], null);
                }

                if (i == 1 && mCurrentXPos[1] < (width - (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2)) && mCurrentYPos[1] >  mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2)
                {
                    mCurrentXPos[1] += mMoveByXPos[1];
                    mCurrentYPos[1] += mMoveByYPos[1];
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), mCurrentXPos[1], mCurrentYPos[1], null);

                }

                else if (i == 1 && mCurrentXPos[1] >= (width - (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2)) || mCurrentYPos[1] <=  mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2)
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(1).getDrawingCache(), width - (width/3), 0, null);
                }

                if (i == 2 && mCurrentXPos[2] > (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2) && mCurrentYPos[2] <  (height - mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2))
                {
                    mCurrentXPos[2] += mMoveByXPos[2];
                    mCurrentYPos[2] += mMoveByYPos[2];
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), mCurrentXPos[2], mCurrentYPos[2], null);
                }

                else if (i == 2 && mCurrentXPos[2] <= (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2) || mCurrentYPos[2] >=  (height - mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2))
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(2).getDrawingCache(), 0, height - (height/4), null);    
                }

                if (i == 3 && mCurrentXPos[3] < (width - (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2)) && mCurrentYPos[3] < (height - mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2))
                {
                    mCurrentXPos[3] += mMoveByXPos[3];
                    mCurrentYPos[3] += mMoveByYPos[3];
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), mCurrentXPos[3], mCurrentYPos[3], null);
                }

                else if (i == 3 && mCurrentXPos[3] >= (width - (mPositive.get(i).getWidth()/2)) || mCurrentYPos[3] >= (height - mPositive.get(i).getHeight()/2))
                {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(3).getDrawingCache(), width - (width/3), height - (height/4), null);    
                }


            }
        }
    }
    h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);

}

protected void moveIt(Canvas canvas, int moveX,int moveY, int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), moveX, moveY, null);
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), moveX, moveY, null);
    }

    if (i == 2)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), moveX, moveY, null);
    }

    if (i == 3)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPositive.get(i).getDrawingCache(), moveX, moveY, null);

    }
}

protected void moveEm(Canvas canvas, int[]mMovePosX, int[] mMovePosY)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

    }
}

protected void ScaleIt(Canvas canvas, int i)
{
    mScale[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mScale[i], (int) (width * 1.5), height, true);
    mScale[i-1].recycle();

}


}
```

And here is the activity:

```
 public class ScaleView extends Activity 
 {  
    Context mContext; 
Scale mScale;
EditText positive_thought;
Button fire;
TextView pos;
private static Set<String> mPositiveWords;
private static Set<String> mNegativeWords;
int count;
private Pattern four_letter_words = Pattern.compile("not|cant|cnt|can't"); 
String inputLine;
private String[] inputTokens;
Button question;
Button skip;

public static boolean populatePositiveWords(Context context)
{
    mNegativeWords = new HashSet<String>();


    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("negative_words.txt")));          
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            mNegativeWords.add(line.toLowerCase(Locale.US));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
    //TODO list of negative words 
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getActionBar().hide();
    mContext = this;
    populatePositiveWords(mContext);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scale);
    mScale = (Scale) findViewById(R.id.anim_view);
    mScale.setClickable(true);
    positive_thought = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thoughts);
    fire = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scale_it);
    skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skip);
    question = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question);
    InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
    FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(60);
    positive_thought.setFilters(FilterArray);


    fire.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            //if the button is clicked invalidate the ondraw method and pass in the text of the positive word 
            inputLine = positive_thought.getText().toString();
            inputTokens = inputLine.split(" ");

            if (inputLine.isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You have to write something!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;                 
            }

            if (inputTokens.length < 3)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "At least three words are required.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }               

            if (four_letter_words.matcher(inputLine).find() == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Make an affirmative statement!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            boolean matchesToken = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < inputTokens.length; i++)
            {
                String token = inputTokens[i];

                if (mNegativeWords.contains(token.toLowerCase(Locale.US)))
                {
                    matchesToken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (matchesToken == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Use positive words!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            else
            {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(
                      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(positive_thought.getWindowToken(), 0);
            pos = new TextView (mContext);
            pos.layout(0, 0, mScale.width/3, mScale.height/4);
            pos.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            pos.setTextSize(15);
            pos.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            pos.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            pos.setShadowLayer(5, 2, 2, Color.YELLOW);
            pos.setText(positive_thought.getText().toString());
            pos.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            pos.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whitecloud);
            pos.setClickable(true);
            mScale.mPositive.add(pos);
            mScale.scale_it = true;
            count++;
            mScale.sStop = false;
            mScale.tracker = count;
            if (count == 4)
            {
                ((RelativeLayout)question.getParent()).removeView(question);
                ((RelativeLayout)skip.getParent()).removeView(skip);
                mScale.mPositive.get(0).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
                        {
                                mScale.mCurrentXPos[0] = event.getX();
                                mScale.mCurrentYPos[0] = event.getY();
                                mScale.mDrag = true;
                                return true;
                        }

                    });


            }



            }
            positive_thought.setText(null);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your TextView cannot receive touch events is that the TextView is drawn on the canvas just as a bitmap, not as a View. An excerpt from your code shown below illustrates this.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvs)
{
    ....
    negative = new TextView(mContext);
    ...
    canvas.drawBitmap(negative.getDrawingCache(), ...)
```

To deliver touch events to your TextView, your Scale class should extend not View but ViewGroup and the TextView needs to be added as a subview to Scale class by using ViewGroup.addView() or addViewInLayout(). It is not a simple task to implement a ViewGroup subclass. You may have to implement onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent) depending on your needs.

Android's source code will be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your CustomView also sets some TouchListner?? 
If yes then this might causing issue..Remove TouchListner from CustomView and see if it works..

Comment: still not working. Not even getting anything with the logcat.

Comment: on Reaching count == 4 are skip & question getting removed from View?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27658/discussion-between-sam-and-akhil)